# Factory error The called function should be payable

Tags: solidity, nft

I am using the Opensea Creatures repository (https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures.git) to make a Factory and create my ERC721 tokens. I have added the function `_setTokenURI (newTokenId, metadataURI);` in ERC721Tradable.sol to add the URI when doing mint but it gives me the following error:

```
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

the files involved are these:

CreatureFactory.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "./IFactoryERC721.sol";
import "./Creature.sol";



contract CreatureFactory is FactoryERC721, Ownable {
    using Strings for string;

    event Transfer(
        address indexed from,
        address indexed to,
        uint256 indexed tokenId
    );

    address public proxyRegistryAddress;
    address public nftAddress;
    address public lootBoxNftAddress;
    string public baseURI = "https://terrorverso.herokuapp.com/api/token/";

    /*
     * Enforce the existence of only 100 OpenSea creatures.
     */
    uint256 CREATURE_SUPPLY = 100;

    /*
     * Three different options for minting Creatures (basic, premium, and gold).
     */
    uint256 NUM_OPTIONS = 3;
    uint256 SINGLE_CREATURE_OPTION = 0;
    uint256 MULTIPLE_CREATURE_OPTION = 1;
    uint256 LOOTBOX_OPTION = 2;
    uint256 NUM_CREATURES_IN_MULTIPLE_CREATURE_OPTION = 4;

    constructor(address _proxyRegistryAddress, address _nftAddress) {
        proxyRegistryAddress = _proxyRegistryAddress;
        nftAddress = _nftAddress;


        fireTransferEvents(address(0), owner());
    }

    function name() override external pure returns (string memory) {
        return "Factory";
    }

    function symbol() override external pure returns (string memory) {
        return "FACT";
    }

    function supportsFactoryInterface() override public pure returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }

    function numOptions() override public view returns (uint256) {
        return NUM_OPTIONS;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) override public onlyOwner {
        address _prevOwner = owner();
        super.transferOwnership(newOwner);
        fireTransferEvents(_prevOwner, newOwner);
    }

    function fireTransferEvents(address _from, address _to) private {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < NUM_OPTIONS; i++) {
            emit Transfer(_from, _to, i);
        }
    }

    function mint(uint256 _optionId, address _toAddress, string memory metadataURI)  override public {
        // Must be sent from the owner proxy or owner.
        ProxyRegistry proxyRegistry = ProxyRegistry(proxyRegistryAddress);
        assert( address(proxyRegistry.proxies(owner())) == _msgSender() || owner() == _msgSender() ||  _msgSender() == lootBoxNftAddress );
        require(canMint(_optionId));

        Creature openSeaCreature = Creature(nftAddress);

        if (_optionId == SINGLE_CREATURE_OPTION) {

            openSeaCreature.mintTo(_toAddress,metadataURI);

        } else if (_optionId == MULTIPLE_CREATURE_OPTION) {
            
            for (
                uint256 i = 0;
                i < NUM_CREATURES_IN_MULTIPLE_CREATURE_OPTION;
                i++
            ) {
                openSeaCreature.mintTo(_toAddress,metadataURI);
            }
        } 
    }

    function canMint(uint256 _optionId) override public view returns (bool) {
        if (_optionId >= NUM_OPTIONS) {
            return false;
        }

        Creature openSeaCreature = Creature(nftAddress);
        uint256 creatureSupply = openSeaCreature.totalSupply();

        uint256 numItemsAllocated = 0;
        if (_optionId == SINGLE_CREATURE_OPTION) {
            numItemsAllocated = 1;
        } else if (_optionId == MULTIPLE_CREATURE_OPTION) {
            numItemsAllocated = NUM_CREATURES_IN_MULTIPLE_CREATURE_OPTION;
        } 
        return creatureSupply < (CREATURE_SUPPLY - numItemsAllocated);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 _optionId) override external view returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, Strings.toString(_optionId)));
    }

    /**
     * Hack to get things to work automatically on OpenSea.
     * Use transferFrom so the frontend doesn't have to worry about different method names.
     */
    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _tokenId,
        string  memory metadataURI
    ) public {
        mint(_tokenId, _to, metadataURI);
    }

    /**
     * Hack to get things to work automatically on OpenSea.
     * Use isApprovedForAll so the frontend doesn't have to worry about different method names.
     */
    function isApprovedForAll(address _owner, address _operator)
        public
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        if (owner() == _owner && _owner == _operator) {
            return true;
        }

        ProxyRegistry proxyRegistry = ProxyRegistry(proxyRegistryAddress);
        if (
            owner() == _owner &&
            address(proxyRegistry.proxies(_owner)) == _operator
        ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Hack to get things to work automatically on OpenSea.
     * Use isApprovedForAll so the frontend doesn't have to worry about different method names.
     */
    function ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns (address _owner) {
        return owner();
    }
}
```

ERC721Tradable.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "./common/meta-transactions/ContentMixin.sol";
import "./common/meta-transactions/NativeMetaTransaction.sol";

contract OwnableDelegateProxy {}

contract ProxyRegistry {
    mapping(address => OwnableDelegateProxy) public proxies;
}

/**
 * @title ERC721Tradable
 * ERC721Tradable - ERC721 contract that whitelists a trading address, and has minting functionality.
 */
abstract contract ERC721Tradable is ContextMixin, ERC721Enumerable, NativeMetaTransaction, Ownable, ERC721URIStorage {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address proxyRegistryAddress;
    uint256 private _currentTokenId = 0;

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        address _proxyRegistryAddress
    ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        proxyRegistryAddress = _proxyRegistryAddress;
        _initializeEIP712(_name);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Mints a token to an address with a tokenURI.
     * @param _to address of the future owner of the token
     */
    function mintTo(address _to, string memory metadataURI) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 newTokenId = _getNextTokenId();
        _mint(_to, newTokenId);
         _setTokenURI(newTokenId, metadataURI);
        _incrementTokenId();
    }

    /**
     * @dev calculates the next token ID based on value of _currentTokenId
     * @return uint256 for the next token ID
     */
    function _getNextTokenId() private view returns (uint256) {
        return _currentTokenId.add(1);
    }

    /**
     * @dev increments the value of _currentTokenId
     */
    function _incrementTokenId() private {
        _currentTokenId++;
    }

    function baseTokenURI() virtual public pure returns (string memory);

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    /**
     * Override isApprovedForAll to whitelist user's OpenSea proxy accounts to enable gas-less listings.
     */
    function isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator)
        override
        public
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        // Whitelist OpenSea proxy contract for easy trading.
        ProxyRegistry proxyRegistry = ProxyRegistry(proxyRegistryAddress);
        if (address(proxyRegistry.proxies(owner)) == operator) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.isApprovedForAll(owner, operator);
    }

    /**
     * This is used instead of msg.sender as transactions won't be sent by the original token owner, but by OpenSea.
     */
    function _msgSender()
        internal
        override
        view
        returns (address sender)
    {
        return ContextMixin.msgSender();
    }
}
```

and Creature.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./ERC721Tradable.sol";


/**
 * @title Creature
 * Creature - a contract for my non-fungible creatures.
 */
contract Creature is ERC721Tradable{
    constructor(address _proxyRegistryAddress)
        ERC721Tradable("ExampleNFT", "EXA", _proxyRegistryAddress)
    {}

    function baseTokenURI() override public pure returns (string memory) {
        return "https://example.com/api/token/";
    }

    function contractURI() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return "https://creatures-api.opensea.io/contract/opensea-creatures";
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: To deploy: first deploy Creature.sol, second CreatureFactory, and the transferOwnership from Creature to CreatureFactory address

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm really struggling with it, tried the above steps to no avail, what proxy address should I use? I'm trying with the OpenSea listed Wyvern one.